# Dojo pre-compile cache ?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to prevent Dojo that it compiles the entire base again. I'd like to reuse compiled Dojo layers/files and add only a thin custom layer .

Now in the build profile, you can set "clean & release" as "action". Both will delete all compiled files again.

ps: I am using the Dojo-Boiler template from Github.

Is it possible at all ?

Thank you